Workflow access denied but still task is completed
I made a simple SharePoint 2013 workflow using SPD in SharePoint 2016. When an item is created, task is assigned to Group2 for approval. There are two security groups.
Group1 - this group can create items
Group2 - this group can approve/reject items
On this list there is another SharePoint 2010 workflow running which set permissions as follows. Initially when workflow is started, both groups have Contribute permission on list item. The workflow removes Contribute permission for user who created item and replace it with Read permission.
Now the problem is when the user who created item, tries to approve workflow, it gets error which is fine (because it has Read permission. But at the same time workflow status is changed to Completed which means task is now complete. This doesn't make any sense!
If the user doesn't have permission and it is throwing error, why task is set to Completed? Because of this workflow gets stuck as now when Group2 tries to do anything, it cannot because task is Completed.
Screenshot given below.

